# Hidden input must not be sent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of `input` with the same `name` and hidden by default.
I show them show based on `select` value and I want to disable hidden inputs so they do not conflict when i submit the form.
How do I do that?

**js**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#report_type").change(function() {
            $("#type_wrap > input").hide();
            $("#" + $(this).val()).show();

        });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `input` property `disabled` to `true` using `.prop("disabled", true)`

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#report_type").change(function() {
            $("#type_wrap > input").prop("disabled", true).hide();
            $("#" + $(this).val()).show();

        });
    });
```

Comment: the input will not show if i put `.prop()` in between.

Comment: @jhunlio Can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: your answer is working when i try to jsfiddle maybe my jquery is the problem

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable an input element, set it's `disabled` property to `true`. To re-enable it, set it's `disabled` property to `false`

```
$("#type_wrap > input").hide().prop('disabled', true);
$("#" + $(this).val()).prop('disabled', false).show();
```

Note: The browser is not supposed to include the values of disabled input elements when the form is submitted. ([reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/forms.html#constructing-form-data-set))

Answer (score 1):

You want to disable inputs that are not visible?

I was thinking of

```
$("#type_wrap > input").not("visible").prop("disabled",true)
```

but this is simpler

```
$(function() {
    $("#report_type").on("change",function() {
        $("#type_wrap > input").prop("disabled",true).hide();
        $("#" + $(this).val()).prop("disabled",false).show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing or hiding the element

**Remove**

```
$("#type_wrap > input").remove();
```

**Disable**

```
 $("#type_wrap > input").prop('disabled', true);
```

This will prevent the element from submitting.